# Can't install Gulp on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, node.js

When I try installing gulp on my ubuntu server I always get these error. I don't know what's wrong? It happens in a new folder after a fresh npm init.

```
martin@serveralpha:/var/www/xyz$ npm install --save-dev gulp
npm WARN xyz@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN xyz@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path /var/www/xyz/node_modules/.array-last.DELETE/node_modules/is-number
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/var/www/xyz/node_modules/.array-last.DELETE/node_modules/is-number' -> '/var/www/xyz/node_modules/array-last/node_modules/is-number'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/martin/.npm/_logs/2019-01-19T17_47_42_221Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The output starts with two warnings.  Have you addressed those?

Comment: Yes, I have, but they are not the problem. Anyway, I have already solved my problem, or at least I know why it is not working. I tried installing gulp in a VMware shared folder on the guest machine. This does not work, but I don't know why. As a workaround, I installed it as host.

Comment: Consider posting an answer to explain your solution.  That will be helpful to others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem, in this case, was that I tried to install gulp in a VMware shared folder, from the guest machine. I don't know why but this does not work. After I tried installing this from the host machine it works.